# Understanding git branches

Tags: git, branch

Newbie git branch question

If I have a simple page like

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>  </head>

    <body>

      This is master

    </body>

    </html>
```

Then crete a new branch and swtch to that branch

```
    git branch new-branch
    git checkout new-branch
```

Then do something in that branch like

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>  </head>

    <body>

      This is master

      This is in the new-branch

    </body>

    </html>
```

I thought this new-branch would be separate from the master and if I switched back to the
master it wouldn't show the content added in the new-branch

If I checkout the master

```
    git checkout master
```

It still shows the content added in the new-branch.

Can anyone explain why this happens.

Comment: You didn't bother committing anything to the branch...

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to commit the changes you made in new-branch.

```
git checkout new-branch

# Do your stuff in <edited_file>

git add <edited_file>
git commit -m "A short desc. of your changes"
git checkout master
```

*NB: You should have first commited your initial file into master branch. Full version:*

```
git init .

vim my_file          # Create some initial content in my_file

git add my_file
git commit -m "My first file"

git branch new-branch
git checkout new-branch

vim my_file          # Add some line to my_file

git add my_file
git commit -m "Some new lines"

git checkout master  # my_file in master does NOT include changes made the second time
```